# 400a Brushed DC Motor Switching Device

Tags: switches

So I'm building what you might call an intentionally janky electric vehicle, and need some advice.

In case anyone is wondering, the vehicle in question is a [Ripstik](https://www.razor.com/products/ripstiks-skateboards/ripstik-caster-board/) -  I currently have four of [these brushed DC motors](https://www.andymark.com/products/2-5-in-cim-motor) driving two 6in pneumatic tires under the back platform, while the front remains un-changed. For all intesive purposes it's an electric skateboard.

My biggest problem is coming switching the motors. You see the aforementioned intentional junkiness is due to the fact that the device is either in full forward, full brake, or coasting - One button for each. Put simply, I'm looking to use some sort of switch to turn the motors on or off - I have no need for an in-between ie some sort of ESC.

The motors I am using are supposedly rated for 130 amp stall current at 12v, but I plan to run them at ~16v for a higher top speed. The batteries that I'm using can supply 400amps in bursts of several seconds.

By my logic, this means that I need a switching device that can switch ~400amps at ~16v, and sustain lesser currents for longer periods of time.

I was initially looking into relays, because they are simple, but the only adequate ones I could find online would have run me 150 USD each, so I was hoping there is some other alternative.

I was looking into N-Channel mosfets, but I have no earthly idea how I would go about using one in this application.

Any and all help is appreciated!!

Comment: I recommend also looking up "contactors" as an option if you only want to turn ON and OFF without worrying too much about speed.

Comment: _"the aforementioned intentional junkiness is due to the fact that the device is either in full forward, full brake, or coasting - One button for each."_ - seems like a very bad idea. What is your reason for such crude operation?

Comment: Bear in mind that when MOSFETs fail, they tend to go dead short circuit leaving you at full power with no means of control.